# Can't build openjdk:8-jdk image directly

Tags: jenkins, docker, java

I'm slowly making my way through the Riot Taking Control of your Docker Image tutorial http://engineering.riotgames.com/news/taking-control-your-docker-image.  This tutorial is a little old, so there are some definite changes to how the end file looks. After hitting several walls I decided to work in the opposite order of the tutorial.  I successfully folded the official jenkinsci image into my personal Dockerfile, starting with FROM: openjdk:8-dk.  But when I try to fold in the openjdk:8-dk file into my personal image I receive the following error

> E: Version '8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1' for 'openjdk-8-jdk' was not found
>   ERROR: Service 'jenkinsmaster' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh
>   -c set -x     && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y       openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"
>         ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]'
>   returned a non-zero code: 100 Cosettes-MacBook-Pro:docker-test
>   Cosette$

I'm receiving this error even when I gave up and directly copied and pasted the openjdk:8-jdk Dockerfile into my own.  My end goal is to bring my personal Dockerfile down to the point that it starts FROM debian-jessie.  Any help would be appreciated.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm

# A few problems with compiling Java from source:
#  1. Oracle.  Licensing prevents us from redistributing the official JDK.
#  2. Compiling OpenJDK also requires the JDK to be installed, and it gets
#       really hairy.

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u102
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1

# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# see CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION notes above
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

# Jenkins Specifics

# install Tini
ENV TINI_VERSION 0.9.0
ENV TINI_SHA fa23d1e20732501c3bb8eeeca423c89ac80ed452

# Use tini as subreaper in Docker container to adopt zombie processes
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static -o /bin/tini && chmod +x /bin/tini \
  && echo "$TINI_SHA  /bin/tini" | sha1sum -c -

# Set Jenkins Environmental Variables
ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home
ENV JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT 50000
    # jenkins version being bundled in this docker image
ARG JENKINS_VERSION
ENV JENKINS_VERSION ${JENKINS_VERSION:-2.19.1}
    # jenkins.war checksum, download will be validated using it
ARG JENKINS_SHA=dc28b91e553c1cd42cc30bd75d0f651671e6de0b
ENV JENKINS_UC https://updates.jenkins.io
ENV COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG $JENKINS_HOME/copy_reference_file.log
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountMax=300 --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log  --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war"
    # Can be used to customize where jenkins.war get downloaded from
ARG JENKINS_URL=http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/${JENKINS_VERSION}/jenkins-war-${JENKINS_VERSION}.war
ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000

# Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000. If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data
# container, ensure you use the same uid.
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
    && useradd -d "$JENKINS_HOME" -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m -s /bin/bash ${user}

# Jenkins home directory is a volume, so configuration and build history
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home

# `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` contains all reference configuration we want
# to set on a fresh new installation. Use it to bundle additional plugins
# or config file with your custom jenkins Docker image.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d

# Install Jenkins. Could use ADD but this one does not check Last-Modified header neither does it
# allow to control checksum. see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8331
RUN curl -fsSL ${JENKINS_URL} -o /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war \
  && echo "${JENKINS_SHA}  /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war" | sha1sum -c -

# Prep Jenkins Directories
USER root
RUN chown -R ${user} "$JENKINS_HOME" /usr/share/jenkins/ref
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R ${group}:${user} /var/log/jenkins
RUN chown -R ${group}:${user} /var/cache/jenkins

# Expose ports for web (8080) & node (50000) agents
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 50000

# Copy in local config filesfiles
COPY init.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy
COPY jenkins-support /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support
COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
    # NOTE : Just set pluginID to download latest version of plugin.
    # NOTE : All plugins need to be listed as there is no transitive dependency resolution.
    # from a derived Dockerfile, can use `RUN plugins.sh active.txt` to setup
    # /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins from a support bundle
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh

# Switch to the jenkins user
USER ${user}

# Tini as the entry point to manage zombie processes
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you try a JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION of `8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1`? The package was updated in Debian's repositories with a security update. I am not sure if old packages with security vulnerabilities are kept around in debian's package repository.

Comment: That totally worked.  Make at an answer so I can choose that for you?  Any idea why what should be the exact same code works when called with a FROM statement in my Dockerfile doesn't work when pasted in the same Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION` of `8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1`

Here's what happens: when you build the docker file, docker tries to execute all the lines in the dockerfile. One of those is this apt command: `apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"`. This comand says "Install OpenJDK version $JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION, exactly. Nothing else.". This version is no longer available in Debian repositories, so it can't be apt-get installed! I believe this happens with all packages in official mirrors: if a new version of the package is released, the older version is no longer around to be installed.

If you want to access older Debian packages, you can use something like http://snapshot.debian.org/. The older OpenJDK package has **known security vulnerabilities**. I recommend using the latest version.

You can use the latest version by leaving out the explicit version in the apt-get command. On the other hand, this will make your image less reproducible: building the image today may get you u111, building it tomorrow may get you u112.

As for why the instructions worked in the other Dockerfile, I think the reason is that at the time the other Dockerfile was built, the package was available. So docker could `apt-get install` it. Docker then built the image containing the (older) OpenJDK. That image is a binary, so you can install it, or use it in `FROM` without any issues. But you can't reproduce the image: if you were to try and build the same image yourself, you would run into the same errors.

This also brings up an issue about security updates: since docker images are effectively static binaries (built once, bundle in all dependencies), they don't get security updates once built. You need to keep track of any security updates affecting your docker images and rebuild any affected docker images.

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation!